Loading assembly with AssemblyResolve in a PowerShell script
I have a super simple .Net (Framework) assembly TestAssembly.dll that contains a public class QuoteServer in a namespae Test and a static method GetQuote() that returns a string.
I want to dynamically load the dll in a Windows PowerShell script through the AssemblyResolve event of the AppDomain class.
It works when I directly load the assembly through Add-Type but it does not work through the AssemblyResolve event.
Trying to use the static method the first results into an failed to load the type error and even in a StackOverflow exception.
Update: the StackOverflow exception is probably caused by the attempt to load System.Management.Automation.resources.dll over and over again.
Here is the script:
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

# Step 1: Define the AssemblyResolve event handler

$AssemblyResolveHandler = [ResolveEventHandler] {
    param(
        [Object]$sender,
        [ResolveEventArgs]$e
    )

    # Extract the assembly name (without the version, culture, or public key)
    $assemblyName = $e.Name.Split(',')[0]
    Write-Host "Resolving assembly: $assemblyName"
    # Some assemblies should not be resolved
    if ($e.assemblyName -like "System.Management.Automation*") {
        return $null
    }
    # Specify the path where your assemblies are located
    $assemblyPath = Join-Path -Path $env:TEMP -ChildPath "TestAssembly.dll"

    # Check if the assembly file exists
    if (Test-Path $assemblyPath) {
        # Load the assembly
        return [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($assemblyPath)
    }

    return $null
}

# Step 2: Register the AssemblyResolve event handler
[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.add_AssemblyResolve($assemblyResolveHandler)
Write-Host "*** AssemblyResolve event handler registered ***"

# Step 3: Attempt to use the type that requires the missing assembly
try {
    [Test.QuoteServer]::GetQuote()
} catch {
    Write-Warning "Failed to load the type. Error: $_"
}

# Now directly load the assembly
$assemblyPath = Join-Path -Path $env:TEMP -ChildPath "TestAssembly.dll"
try {
    Add-Type -Path $assemblyPath
    [Test.QuoteServer]::GetQuote()
} catch {
    $_.Exception.LoaderExceptions
}



The very first thing I'd try is renaming $args in the event handler, eg. [ResolveEventArgs]$REArgs

I'm still thinking what is causing error.  I believe it has to do with following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-data#thread-local-storage

A type literal with the target type name alone is not enough - you need to supply an assembly name to trigger lookup of that specific assembly:
try {
    [Test.QuoteServer, TestAssembly]::GetQuote() 
    # now that PowerShell has an assembly name to look for ("TestAssembly"), it'll raise AssemblyResolve
} catch {
    Write-Warning "Failed to load the type. Error: $_"
}


Additionally, you'll want to avoid reusing the name of the automatic variable $args for user-defined parameters - call it literally anything else:
$AssemblyResolveHandler = [ResolveEventHandler] {
    param(
        [Object]$sender,
        [ResolveEventArgs]$eArgs
    )

    # ...
}


That does not work in Windows PowerShell (?)

If works with PowerShell 7.x and not using the assembly name
